# How to Generate dyamic columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot

I have 5 columns (A,B,C,D,E) which contain data as

```
A   ||  B  ||  c    ||  d      ||    E      
1      1       301      1000      somedates 
1      2       301      1001                
1      3       302      1002                
1      4       303      1001
1      5       304      1000
1      6       305      1001
```

[image]

I want to display data as
Column C,D,E will appear as total rows 
For each row CDE column will be exist.
Based on column B ID

Here I have added image 1st is data and next the output format where Columns (headID,grade,AssignDate) repeated as no. of rows available in headCategoriesID column

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense.  Try editing your question.  Format the table by putting four spaces in front of each row.  And, include desired results for the sample data.

Comment: how your desired result looks like?

Comment: Pls chk image and description

Comment: I am new postgresql  bt tried for pivot... can pls suggest any way.. I will try fr that

Comment: Search for "crosstab" instead, then. Pivots and crosstabulations are annoyingly hard in PostgreSQL. I can't really give you an example with your query, because it's a pile of confusing screenshots, not actual `create table` and `insert` statements that I can use.

Comment: thanks.. will try for that...